# Jersey 2.3 Interceptor Example not working

Tags: rest, jersey, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to get the Jersey 2.3 Interceptor example [found here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/2.3.1/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e6857) using Tomcat 7 and name binding to work. I've created the following as per the example shown in the link...

```java
@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Compress{}
```

and

```java
@Compress
public class GZIPWriterInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {
@Override
public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
  final OuputStream outputStream .....  
  ..some logging added here..
}
```

and

```java
@Path("helloword")
public class HelloWorldResource {

  @GET
  @Path("to-much-data")
  @Compress
  public String getVeryLongString(){
    String str = "a very ...
    ..... large string";
    return str;
  }
}
```

I haven't added anything extra to the web.xml to register the Interceptor as this wasn't discussed in the User Guide documentation. I note that this was the method used in ealier version of Jersey.

I tested if the compression Interceptor worked using a client built from the jersey client api. I've ensured the `HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip"` Header is added to the `Invocation.Builder` prior to sending the request. I've also added logging to `GZIPWriterInterceptor`. When I test to see if the response is zipped it comes back in plain text (`Content-Type - text/plain` is set in the response header) and I don't see the `GZIPWriterInterceptor` message in the logs.

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong or what else I could try?

**EDIT** - I updated my web.xml to attempt to register the GZIPWriterInterceptor class.

```html
......
.
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Jersey Test Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-value>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-value>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.test.jersey</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.ws.rs.ext.WriterInterceptor</param-name>
    <param-value>com.test.jersey.GZIPWriterInterceptor</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
.
.......
```

This hasn't worked. Do I register the GZIPWriterInterceptor with the parameter name of WriterInterceptor or something else?

**UPDATE** - I've managed to get the compression to work by extending javax.ws.rs.core.Application and registering each class I require (HelloWorldResource.class, GZIPWriterInterceptor.class, Compress.class) as discribed in the Deployment Agnostic Application Model [found here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/2.3.1/deployment.html).

I registered my Application class in the web.xml...

```html
<display-name>JerseyInterceptorTest2</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Rest Test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.jersey.test.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Jersey Rest Test</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

I tried unsuccessfully to register my packages by extending ResourceConfig as per Example 4.2. and by the earlier method throught the web.xml

```html
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.test.jersey</param-value>
</init-param>
```

It's still not clear why package registration doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

There are two things you need to do:

1. From provided code snippet it doesn't seem that your `WriterInterceptor` is annotated with `@Compress` annotation. Please, do so to make sure your provider and resource method are matched together.
2. You need to register the provider in your JAX-RS `Application` class or through `web.xml`. The documentation might be a little vague about this (we'll fix that).

Comment: Thanks Michal, I added @Compress and updated the web.xml to include what I thought was needed to register GZIPWriterInterceptor. I'll add this as an edit to my original question.

Comment: Your param-name is wrong. It should be `jersey.config.server.provider.classnames` instead of `com.ws.rs.ext.WriterInterceptor`.

Comment: I've got that in the web.xml. I'm using packages to register the provider.

Answer (score 5):

Interceptor Class has to be annotated with `@Provider` too, like this:

```
@Provider
@Compress
public class GZIPWriterInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor { ...
```

This will then get picked up in a package scan.

The docs [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9976) don't specify that explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all the classes(Compress,GZIPWriterInterceptor,HelloWorldResource) are under the same package specified by parameter "jersey.config.server.provider.packages" in web.xml.

It occurred to me a situation that the @NameBinding not working, and I found out that I placed the Compress into another package.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not forget to put @Provider annotation above writer class
2. Put Writer, Compress and the resource in same package
3. (Most important): Register the classes on application class:

```java
        @ApplicationPath("myrest")
        public class MyRestApplication extends Application{

        @Override
        public Set<Object> getSingletons() {

            Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
            singletons.add(new AuthorResource());
            singletons.add(new GZipWriterInterceptor());
            singletons.add(new EncodingFilter());
            singletons.add(new GZipEncoder());
            return singletons;
          } 
        }
```